# Integration of combination of trigonometric function and Bessel function with complicated arguments

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Do the integrals below have solutions?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(Qt)J_{0}\left(A\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(Qt)J_{2}\left(A\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\cos(Qt)J_{0}\left(A\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sin(Qt)J_{0}\left(A\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\cos(Qt)J_{2}\left(A\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sin(Qt)J_{2}\left(A\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)dt$$

where, $A$ and $Q$ are constants; $J_{0}$ and $J_{2}$ are the zetoth and second order Bessel functions of first kind respectively.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please make the question a little more clear. What is $Q$? What are $J_0$ and $J_2$? What is the context of trying to integrate these functions?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is now corrected.

Comment: I'd start by investigating whether these integrals actually converge. If $Q$ is rational, then the integrands are periodic (with period of $n\pi$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$), continuous, and not identically zero (unless $A=0$ in the second integrand).